# sorting ps output by CPU time on linux

Tags: linux, ps

I want to sort ps output by process CPU time ("TIME" column).
I've tried:

```
ps -aux --sort cputime | tail
```

but it doesn't sort by cpu time.
I'm running with:

```
ps --version 
procps version 3.2.7
```

and kernel: 2.6.18

Comment: This works on Debian 7.8 (wheezy); procps-ng version 3.3.3.  Can you share more about the system you're running?  What is the output of `ps --version`?

Comment: Added missing info @Jander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not cputime but time that u want :)

```
ps -aux --sort -time
```

Just post after `--sort` the exact name of the column that you want.

with tail:

```
ps -aux --sort +time | tail
```

`+-`  for selecting order

Comment: Trying your command resulted with: ERROR: User name does not exist.

Comment: it is working for me at Ubunti 15.04. Try aux without the dash

Answer (score 0):

This sorts by CPU:

```
ps aux --sort -pcpu
```

This is how it's done!

Answer (score 0):

The questioner wanted to sort by the "TIME" column (displayed when you run ps -aux), which is how I ended up here, wanting the same thing. This column contains the *TOTAL* CPU execution time (on Ubuntus anyway, your linux may vary).

Neither of the 2 answers worked for me. But a combination of those answers with the original question led to the correct command. The questioner just needed to add a dash in front of the cputime flag:

```
ps -aux --sort -cputime
```

This displays a list of processes, sorted in descending order by *total cpu execution time* since last reboot.